# Elimination of Cannabis Manufacturing/Processing?

Tags: claims, application

In reference to the patent: [US20170290869](https://www.google.com/patents/US20170290869)

Seems this patent would eliminate or preclude 100's of companies in states where cannabis processing is legal, most companies are now processing by CO2 extraction to obtain active cannabinoids including THC and CBD being the main constituents. Is the author(s) making a claim on their particular extraction conditions or methodology or trying to encompass the entire "extraction by CO2" process, an already burgeoning industry in states like CO and CA.

Comment: Hint, it isn’t a patent, it’s an application.

Comment: If you are worried about this application, check out this issued patent: https://patents.google.com/patent/US7344736B2/en

Answer (score 1):

Looking at very the beginning of the application you will see -

> This application is a continuation of Ser. No. 12/049,588, filed Mar.
>   17, 2008, now pending, which is a divisional of U.S. patent
>   application Ser. No. 10/218,972, filed Aug. 14, 2002, now [U.S. Pat.
>   No. 7,344,736](https://patents.google.com/patent/US7344736B2/en), the entire contents of each of which are incorporated
>   herein by reference in their entireties.

That says the initial filing was done in 2002 so your feeling that it is old only matters if it was old as of Aug. 14th 2002.

Comment: I added a link to US7344736 which covers much the same technology and is an issued patent.